# Kafka Metric gauges being cleaned up on GC / consumer rebalance with Spring-kafka

Tags: prometheus, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-micrometer

I am using Spring cloud Stream with spring-kafka for one of my application and it appears that whenever there is consumer rebalance or GC, the kafka consumer lag gauges are garbage collected due to weak references, hence returning NaN.

I see someone having similar issue mentioned here and steps to reproduce it. https://issueexplorer.com/issue/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/2726

Anyone facing similar issue and any workaround for it?

We would like to autoscale our application based on lag gauge.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in micrometer-core 1.7.4.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).